# Primality of $2^q\pm2^{(q+1)/2}+1$ when $q$ is an odd integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

It can be quite easily shown that $5$ is a divisor of $2^q+2^{(q+1)/2}+1$ iff ($q=8k+1$ or $q=8k+7$) and that $5$ is a divisor of $2^q-2^{(q+1)/2}+1$ iff ($q=8k+3$ or $q=8k+5$).

Now, it seems that for $2^q\pm2^{(q+1)/2}+1$ to be prime, it is necessary that $q$ be prime.  Is this true? If yes, is there an elementary proof?  I have hard time to find one.

Comment: If my program was right, no primes upto $q=2^{30}$ I think.

Comment: oh no my bad. I forgot to add the $1$. How naive.

Comment: Perhaps you already found that $2^q\pm2^{\frac{q+1}2}+1=\frac12((2^{\frac{q+1}2}\pm1)^2+1)$ but I'm not sure if it helps.

Comment: What you're looking for are http://oeis.org/A007671 and http://oeis.org/A007670. Your conjecture has not been mentioned there, but it seems true as far as OEIS goes, I checked primality of all numbers.

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful, beacuse I checked OEIS and they give antother prime sequence http://oeis.org/A057429 that includes $2^q\pm2^{(q+1)/2}+1$. From that new sequence a proof that $2^q\pm2^{(q+1)/2}+1$ can be prime only for $q$ prime is very easily derived, I think.  see above

Answer (score 1):

Beginnings: the product of the two expressions is $4^q + 1,$ with $q$ odd.  If $q = r s,$ we know that $4^{rs} + 1$ is divisible by both $4^r + 1$ and $4^s + 1.$

More to come.

Well, what I suspect: let's make $s$ prime, it may be important. If $s \equiv \pm 3 \pmod 8,$ then it appears that $$ \gcd \left(  2^r + 2^{(r+1)/2} + 1,  2^{rs} + 2^{(rs+1)/2} + 1  \right) = 1,  $$ and
$$ \gcd \left(  2^r - 2^{(r+1)/2} + 1,  2^{rs} - 2^{(rs+1)/2} + 1  \right) = 1.  $$

If $s \equiv \pm 1 \pmod 8,$ then it appears that $$ \gcd \left(  2^r + 2^{(r+1)/2} + 1,  2^{rs} - 2^{(rs+1)/2} + 1  \right) = 1,  $$ and
$$ \gcd \left(  2^r - 2^{(r+1)/2} + 1,  2^{rs} + 2^{(rs+1)/2} + 1  \right) = 1.  $$

If these work out, they give the whole package, using the initial observation about $4^q + 1.$ The outcome is that each piece is divisible by either the same or the opposite piece for any smaller $q$ value that divides the current, composite, $q.$ Worth checking these patterns for larger $q.$ It is not necessary to factor the numbers to confirm the gcd pattern, so large $q$ is acceptable.

```
TABLE:
       q   minus        plus
1      3  5 = 5     13 = 13
2      5  25 = 5^2     41 = 41
3      7  113 = 113     145 = 5 29
4      9  481 = 13 37     545 = 5 109
5     11  1985 = 5 397     2113 = 2113
6     13  8065 = 5 1613     8321 = 53 157
7     15  32513 = 13 41 61     33025 = 5^2 1321
8     17  130561 = 137 953     131585 = 5 26317
9     19  523265 = 5 229 457     525313 = 525313
10     21  2095105 = 5 29 14449     2099201 = 13 113 1429
11     23  8384513 = 277 30269     8392705 = 5 1013 1657
12     25  33546241 = 41 101 8101     33562625 = 5^3 268501
13     27  134201345 = 5 109 246241     134234113 = 13 37 279073
14     29  536838145 = 5 107367629     536903681 = 536903681
15     31  2147418113 = 5581 384773     2147549185 = 5 8681 49477
16     33  8589803521 = 13 2113 312709     8590065665 = 5 397 4327489
17     35  34359476225 = 5^2 29 47392381     34360000513 = 41 113 7416361
18     37  137438429185 = 5 149 184481113     137439477761 = 593 231769777
19     39  549754765313 = 13^2 53 157 313 1249     549756862465 = 5 1613 3121 21841
20     41  2199021158401 = 181549 12112549     2199025352705 = 5 10169 43249589
       q       minus                                  plus
```

---

For what it's worth, i did the gcd tests I described for $q \leq 149.$ Whenever $q$ was composite, i took gcd's of the two $\pm$ factors with those of any factor $k.$ Results as i expected. Results go by the ratio modulo 8. So, somewhere there is a Jacobi symbol $(2 | q)$ hiding. Oh, I did not print out the gcd if larger than 1, I just said to write the word "big." We know what the gcd is when the other on the same line is 1.

---

```
smaller
3 small    5

5 small    25

7 small    113

9 small    481
3  ratio 3 ==  3        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 

11 small    1985

13 small    8065

15 small    32513
3  ratio 5 ==  5        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 
5  ratio 3 ==  3        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 

17 small    130561

19 small    523265

21 small    2095105
3  ratio 7 ==  7        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1
7  ratio 3 ==  3        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 

23 small    8384513

25 small    33546241
5  ratio 5 ==  5        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 

27 small    134201345
3  ratio 9 ==  1        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1
9  ratio 3 ==  3        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 

29 small    536838145

31 small    2147418113

33 small    8589803521
3  ratio 11 ==  3        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 
11  ratio 3 ==  3        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 

35 small    34359476225
5  ratio 7 ==  7        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1
7  ratio 5 ==  5        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 

37 small    137438429185

39 small    549754765313
3  ratio 13 ==  5        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 
13  ratio 3 ==  3        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 

41 small    2199021158401

43 small    8796088827905

45 small    35184363700225
3  ratio 15 ==  7        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1
5  ratio 9 ==  1        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1
9  ratio 5 ==  5        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 
15  ratio 3 ==  3        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 

47 small    140737471578113

49 small    562949919866881
7  ratio 7 ==  7        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1

51 small    2251799746576385
3  ratio 17 ==  1        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1
17  ratio 3 ==  3        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 

53 small    9007199120523265

55 small    36028796750528513
5  ratio 11 ==  3        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 
11  ratio 5 ==  5        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 

57 small    144115187538984961
3  ratio 19 ==  3        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 
19  ratio 3 ==  3        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 

59 small    576460751229681665

61 small    2305843007066210305

63 small    9223372032559808513
3  ratio 21 ==  5        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 
7  ratio 9 ==  1        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1
9  ratio 7 ==  7        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1
21  ratio 3 ==  3        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 

65 small    36893488138829168641
5  ratio 13 ==  5        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 
13  ratio 5 ==  5        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 

67 small    147573952572496543745

69 small    590295810324345913345
3  ratio 23 ==  7        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1
23  ratio 3 ==  3        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 

71 small    2361183241366103130113

73 small    9444732965601851473921

75 small    37778931862682283802625
3  ratio 25 ==  1        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1
5  ratio 15 ==  7        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1
15  ratio 5 ==  5        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 
25  ratio 3 ==  3        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 

77 small    151115727451278891024385
7  ratio 11 ==  3        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 
11  ratio 7 ==  7        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1

79 small    604462909806215075725313

81 small    2417851639227059326156801
3  ratio 27 ==  3        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 
9  ratio 9 ==  1        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1
27  ratio 3 ==  3        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 

83 small    9671406556912635351138305

85 small    38685626227659337497575425
5  ratio 17 ==  1        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1
17  ratio 5 ==  5        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 

87 small    154742504910654942176346113
3  ratio 29 ==  5        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 
29  ratio 3 ==  3        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 

89 small    618970019642654953077473281

91 small    2475880078570690181054070785
7  ratio 13 ==  5        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 
13  ratio 7 ==  7        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1

93 small    9903520314282901461704638465
3  ratio 31 ==  7        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1
31  ratio 3 ==  3        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 

95 small    39614081257131887321795264513
5  ratio 19 ==  3        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 
19  ratio 5 ==  5        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 

97 small    158456325028528112237134479361

99 small    633825300114113574848444760065
3  ratio 33 ==  1        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1
9  ratio 11 ==  3        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 
11  ratio 9 ==  1        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1
33  ratio 3 ==  3        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 

101 small    2535301200456456551193592725505

103 small    10141204801825830708373998272513

105 small    40564819207303331840695247831041
3  ratio 35 ==  3        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 
5  ratio 21 ==  5        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 
7  ratio 15 ==  7        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1
15  ratio 7 ==  7        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1
21  ratio 5 ==  5        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 
35  ratio 3 ==  3        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 

107 small    162259276829213345377179500806145

109 small    649037107316853417537515022188545

111 small    2596148429267413742207654126682113
3  ratio 37 ==  5        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 
37  ratio 3 ==  3        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 

113 small    10384593717069655112945804582584321

115 small    41538374868278620740013594482049025
5  ratio 23 ==  7        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1
23  ratio 5 ==  5        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 

117 small    166153499473114483536515130231619585
3  ratio 39 ==  7        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1
9  ratio 13 ==  5        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 
13  ratio 9 ==  1        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1
39  ratio 3 ==  3        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 

119 small    664613997892457935298982025533325313
7  ratio 17 ==  1        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1
17  ratio 7 ==  7        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1

121 small    2658455991569831743501771111346995201
11  ratio 11 ==  3        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 

123 small    10633823966279326978618770463815368705
3  ratio 41 ==  1        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1
41  ratio 3 ==  3        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 

125 small    42535295865117307923698453892116250625
5  ratio 25 ==  1        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1
25  ratio 5 ==  5        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 

127 small    170141183460469231713240559642174554113

129 small    680564733841876926889855726716117319681
3  ratio 43 ==  3        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 
43  ratio 3 ==  3        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 

131 small    2722258935367507707633209883159307485185

133 small    10889035741470030830680413485226906353665
7  ratio 19 ==  3        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 
19  ratio 7 ==  7        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1

135 small    43556142965880123323016801846086978240513
3  ratio 45 ==  5        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 
5  ratio 27 ==  3        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 
9  ratio 15 ==  7        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1
15  ratio 9 ==  1        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1
27  ratio 5 ==  5        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 
45  ratio 3 ==  3        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 

137 small    174224571863520493292657503194706618613761

139 small    696898287454081973171810604399543885758465

141 small    2787593149816327892689603600839610365640705
3  ratio 47 ==  7        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1
47  ratio 3 ==  3        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 

143 small    11150372599265311570763136769841311107776513
11  ratio 13 ==  5        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 
13  ratio 11 ==  3        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 

145 small    44601490397061246283061991812330983721533441
5  ratio 29 ==  5        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 
29  ratio 5 ==  5        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 

147 small    178405961588244985132266856715255413466988545
3  ratio 49 ==  1        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1
7  ratio 21 ==  5        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 
21  ratio 7 ==  7        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1
49  ratio 3 ==  3        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 

149 small    713623846352979940529105205792884611029663745



bigger
3 big    13

5 big    41

7 big    145

9 big    545
3  ratio 3 ==  3        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1

11 big    2113

13 big    8321

15 big    33025
3  ratio 5 ==  5        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1
5  ratio 3 ==  3        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1

17 big    131585

19 big    525313

21 big    2099201
3  ratio 7 ==  7        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 
7  ratio 3 ==  3        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1

23 big    8392705

25 big    33562625
5  ratio 5 ==  5        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1

27 big    134234113
3  ratio 9 ==  1        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 
9  ratio 3 ==  3        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1

29 big    536903681

31 big    2147549185

33 big    8590065665
3  ratio 11 ==  3        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1
11  ratio 3 ==  3        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1

35 big    34360000513
5  ratio 7 ==  7        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 
7  ratio 5 ==  5        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1

37 big    137439477761

39 big    549756862465
3  ratio 13 ==  5        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1
13  ratio 3 ==  3        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1

41 big    2199025352705

43 big    8796097216513

45 big    35184380477441
3  ratio 15 ==  7        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 
5  ratio 9 ==  1        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 
9  ratio 5 ==  5        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1
15  ratio 3 ==  3        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1

47 big    140737505132545

49 big    562949986975745
7  ratio 7 ==  7        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 

51 big    2251799880794113
3  ratio 17 ==  1        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 
17  ratio 3 ==  3        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1

53 big    9007199388958721

55 big    36028797287399425
5  ratio 11 ==  3        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1
11  ratio 5 ==  5        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1

57 big    144115188612726785
3  ratio 19 ==  3        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1
19  ratio 3 ==  3        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1

59 big    576460753377165313

61 big    2305843011361177601

63 big    9223372041149743105
3  ratio 21 ==  5        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1
7  ratio 9 ==  1        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 
9  ratio 7 ==  7        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 
21  ratio 3 ==  3        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1

65 big    36893488156009037825
5  ratio 13 ==  5        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1
13  ratio 5 ==  5        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1

67 big    147573952606856282113

69 big    590295810393065390081
3  ratio 23 ==  7        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 
23  ratio 3 ==  3        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1

71 big    2361183241503542083585

73 big    9444732965876729380865

75 big    37778931863232039616513
3  ratio 25 ==  1        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 
5  ratio 15 ==  7        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 
15  ratio 5 ==  5        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1
25  ratio 3 ==  3        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1

77 big    151115727452378402652161
7  ratio 11 ==  3        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1
11  ratio 7 ==  7        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 

79 big    604462909808414098980865

81 big    2417851639231457372667905
3  ratio 27 ==  3        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1
9  ratio 9 ==  1        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 
27  ratio 3 ==  3        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1

83 big    9671406556921431444160513

85 big    38685626227676929683619841
5  ratio 17 ==  1        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 
17  ratio 5 ==  5        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1

87 big    154742504910690126548434945
3  ratio 29 ==  5        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1
29  ratio 3 ==  3        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1

89 big    618970019642725321821650945

91 big    2475880078570830918542426113
7  ratio 13 ==  5        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1
13  ratio 7 ==  7        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 

93 big    9903520314283182936681349121
3  ratio 31 ==  7        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 
31  ratio 3 ==  3        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1

95 big    39614081257132450271748685825
5  ratio 19 ==  3        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1
19  ratio 5 ==  5        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1

97 big    158456325028529238137041321985

99 big    633825300114115826648258445313
3  ratio 33 ==  1        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 
9  ratio 11 ==  3        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1
11  ratio 9 ==  1        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 
33  ratio 3 ==  3        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1

101 big    2535301200456461054793220096001

103 big    10141204801825839715573253013505

105 big    40564819207303349855093757313025
3  ratio 35 ==  3        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1
5  ratio 21 ==  5        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1
7  ratio 15 ==  7        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 
15  ratio 7 ==  7        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 
21  ratio 5 ==  5        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1
35  ratio 3 ==  3        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1

107 big    162259276829213381405976519770113

109 big    649037107316853489595109060116481

111 big    2596148429267413886322842202537985
3  ratio 37 ==  5        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1
37  ratio 3 ==  3        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1

113 big    10384593717069655401176180734296065

115 big    41538374868278621316474346785472513
5  ratio 23 ==  7        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 
23  ratio 5 ==  5        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1

117 big    166153499473114484689436634838466561
3  ratio 39 ==  7        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 
9  ratio 13 ==  5        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1
13  ratio 9 ==  1        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 
39  ratio 3 ==  3        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1

119 big    664613997892457937604825034747019265
7  ratio 17 ==  1        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 
17  ratio 7 ==  7        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 

121 big    2658455991569831748113457129774383105
11  ratio 11 ==  3        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1

123 big    10633823966279326987842142500670144513
3  ratio 41 ==  1        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 
41  ratio 3 ==  3        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1

125 big    42535295865117307942145197965825802241
5  ratio 25 ==  1        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 
25  ratio 5 ==  5        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1

127 big    170141183460469231750134047789593657345

129 big    680564733841876926963642703010955526145
3  ratio 43 ==  3        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1
43  ratio 3 ==  3        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1

131 big    2722258935367507707780783835748983898113

133 big    10889035741470030830975561390406259179521
7  ratio 19 ==  3        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1
19  ratio 7 ==  7        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 

135 big    43556142965880123323607097656445683892225
3  ratio 45 ==  5        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1
5  ratio 27 ==  3        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1
9  ratio 15 ==  7        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 
15  ratio 9 ==  1        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 
27  ratio 5 ==  5        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1
45  ratio 3 ==  3        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1

137 big    174224571863520493293838094815424029917185

139 big    696898287454081973174171787640978708365313

141 big    2787593149816327892694325967322480010854401
3  ratio 47 ==  7        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 
47  ratio 3 ==  3        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1

143 big    11150372599265311570772581502807050398203905
11  ratio 13 ==  5        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1
13  ratio 11 ==  3        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1

145 big    44601490397061246283080881278262462302388225
5  ratio 29 ==  5        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1
29  ratio 5 ==  5        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1

147 big    178405961588244985132304635647118370628698113
3  ratio 49 ==  1        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 
7  ratio 21 ==  5        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1
21  ratio 7 ==  7        gcd_minus   1                      gcd_plus     big 
49  ratio 3 ==  3        gcd_minus     big                       gcd_plus   1

149 big    713623846352979940529180763656610525353082881
```

---

Comment: Thank you!  that is very insightful. This make me think a key to a proof is in proving that whenever $q$ is composite, $Q_q^\pm= 2^q\pm2^{(q+1)/2}+1$ is divisible by either $Q_k^+$ or $Q_k^-$, where $k$ is a proper divisor of $q$

Comment: @RenéGy, yes. Meanwhile, i just did a check on the second output, no room left to post it. The behavior you are thinking about really is defined by the value of $q/k \pmod 8.$ You don't get this kind of complete adherence to a pattern unless there is a relatively elementary proof, but elementary need not mean easy or short. Before I forget, all prime factors of the $Q_q$ are $\equiv 1 \pmod 4,$ as they are also factors of $$ 4^q + 1 = \left( 2^q \right)^2 + 1.  $$ Here the 2 and the 4 are not that important, it is the 1 that matters.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proposal for a proof of the statement that $Q_p^{\pm}$ is prime implies that $p$ is prime.
It is based of the relationship : 
$Q_p=((1+i)^p-1)((1-i)^p-1)=2^p+e(p)2^{(p+1)/2}+1$
where $p$ is an odd positive integer, $e(p)=-1$ when $p=8k\pm1$ and $e(p)=+1$ when $p=8k\pm3$.

This is easily derived, if you write $1\pm{i}= \sqrt2.exp(\pm{i}\pi/4$).

Then $Q_p=Q_p^-$ when $p=8k\pm1$ and $Q_p=Q_p^+$ when $p=8k\pm3$. (Note that when $p=8k\pm1$, $Q_p^+$ is divisible by $5$, and therefore composite, and when $p=8k\pm3$, $Q_p^-$ is divisible by $5$, and therefore composite, too.)

Now suppose that $p$ is composite and let $q$ be a proper divisor of $p$. Then $((1+i)^p-1)((1-i)^p-1) = [((1+i)^q-1)R((1+i)^q)][((1-i)^q-1)R((1-i)^q)]$, where R is a polynomial of degree $p/q-1$.

That is $Q_p=Q_q.R((1+i)^q)R((1-i)^q)$ which says that $Q_q$ is a proper divisor of $Q_p$. (Note that $e(p)$ and $e(q)$ may differ in sign).
Conversely, if $Q_p$ is prime, then $p$ is prime. Q.E.D.

PS: From the research I have done, these primes $Q_p$ have a name: they are the "Gaussian Mersenne primes". In 2006, 37 were known, the largest one is $2^{1203793} - 2^{601897} +1$.